# How to connect Oracle Cloud from Mule ESB?

Tags: mule, eloqua

To connect Solesforce cloud we have salesforce component in mule.

But to connect Oracle Eloqua i couldn't find any such connector, please can anybody share the proper document link or way to connect?

Thanks...,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the documentation on 
https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-901520, hope it may help